# Posterior distribution of normal with gamma prior on the precision

Tags: self-study, bayesian, inference, posterior

> Find the posterior distribution when
>
> $$x|\sigma\sim \mathcal N(0,\sigma^2),\:\:\: 1/\sigma^2\sim \mathsf{Gamma}(1,2)$$

I'm stuck in this exercise, I know that $$\pi(x|\sigma)\approx f(x|\sigma)\pi(\sigma)\cdot\frac{1}{m(x)}$$

Maybe I am thinking wrong, but I would not have to find a prior of $\sigma$?

Comment: Is that the quotient of $x, \sigma$, or $x$ given $\sigma$?

Comment: @SeanEaster the pdf is given and the other is $\frac{1}{\sigma^2}$

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: @amoeba, I believe I voted to close as SS, although I don't really remember anymore. You can vote to reopen if you like.

Comment: Could you explain what the symbols "$m$", "$f$", and "$\pi$" mean to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In effect, you know the prior on $\sigma^2$: It's [inverse gamma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-gamma_distribution). After expressing the posterior as the product of normal likelihood and inverse-gamma prior, one can manipulate the posterior until it's recognizable as another inverse gamma. (Left as an exercise, but confirmed in [Michael I. Jordan - The Conjugate Prior for the Normal Distribution](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/%7Ejordan/courses/260-spring10/lectures/lecture5.pdf))